# How to add title attribute to views trimmed title field?

Tags: navigation, views

The title field of a view is trimmed to 40 characters, and the Title field is linked to it's content. Since the Title field text is trimmed I need to add `title` attribute to the `<a>` tag of the Title field and the content of the `title` attribute must be the non-trimmed version of the Title field. So on mouseover event it should show the non-trimmed Title field text. How do I can do this?

I tried this

```
 function THEME_preprocess_link(&$vars) {
    // If title set and not empty dont do anything
    if (isset($vars['options']['attributes']['title']) && !empty($vars['options']['attributes']['title'])) {
        return;
    }

    // Use the link text as the title
    $vars['options']['attributes']['title'] = strip_tags($vars['text']);
 }
```

But it shows the trimmed version as the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accomplish this by overriding the field tpl file for the field and view:

- assuming a View called 'title_test', and a field named 'title'
- under Advanced, Theme, it gives the following option for the field tpl file: views-view-field--title-test--title.tpl.php
- copy the modules/views/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php to your themes template folder, and rename it to views-view-field--title-test--title.tpl.php
- replace the existing $output code with:

  ```
  <?php
      $field_output = l($field->last_render_text, $field->options['alter']['path'], array('attributes' => array('title' => $field->original_value)));
      print $field_output;
  ?>
  ```
- clear the cache

BE AWARE that this is overriding the default output by manually creating the link, so any special classes, or formatting included in the View must be added to this or you get unexpected behaviour (like missing classes, or field styling, etc). All of the information is available in the $field variable, you just need to extract it, for which [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and `dpm($field);` will prove invaluable:

> Devel Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins.
>   This module can print a summary of all database queries for each page
>   request at the bottom of each page. The summary includes how many
>   times each query was executed on a page (shouldn't run same query
>   multiple times), and how long each query took (short is good - use
>   cache for complex queries). Also a dprint_r($array) function is
>   provided, which pretty prints arrays. Useful during development.
>   Similarly, a ddebug_backtrace() is offerred.